# Tried to add Visual Studio solution to github - empty repository

Tags: visual-studio, github

I'm trying to add my Visual Studio solution to github. I've tried following the instructions to use the Add to Source Control button:
[image]

But I have only managed to create an empty repository. I can't get the files to upload.

My Team Explorer shows:
[image: team explorer screengrab]

My Git Changes tab won't let me push or update since it thinks I have no changes to stage:
[image]

How do I add/commit/push my files to Github?

Answer (score 0):

Initially my Git Changes showed this:
[image]

I fixed things by later closing and re-opening Visual Studio and returned to find that the Changes section was full of my files. So I could then commit and push.